# generate monochrome bitmap image using c

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I am writing code to generate monochrome bmp image out of array. there are plenty of tools to generate bmp to array but i want it in reverse way. i found lots of code but it was color image. 
here is code i am trying...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define _height 64
#define _width 128
#define _bitsperpixel 1
#define _planes 1
#define _compression 0
#define _pixelbytesize _height*_width*_bitsperpixel/8
#define _filesize _pixelbytesize+sizeof(bitmap)
#define _xpixelpermeter 0x130B //2835 , 72 DPI
#define _ypixelpermeter 0x130B //2835 , 72 DPI
#define pixel 0x55
#pragma pack(push,1)

unsigned char arr[8192]={0};

typedef struct{
    uint8_t signature[2];
    uint32_t filesize;
    uint32_t reserved;
    uint32_t fileoffset_to_pixelarray;
} fileheader;
typedef struct{
    uint32_t dibheadersize;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitsperpixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t ypixelpermeter;
    uint32_t xpixelpermeter;
    uint32_t numcolorspallette;
    uint32_t mostimpcolor;
} bitmapinfoheader;
typedef struct {
    fileheader fileheader;
    bitmapinfoheader bitmapinfoheader;
} bitmap;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main (int argc , char *argv[]) {
int i;
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.bmp","wb");
    bitmap *pbitmap  = (bitmap*)calloc(1,sizeof(bitmap));
    uint8_t *pixelbuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(_pixelbytesize);
    strcpy(pbitmap->fileheader.signature,"BM");
    pbitmap->fileheader.filesize = _filesize;
    pbitmap->fileheader.fileoffset_to_pixelarray = sizeof(bitmap);
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.dibheadersize =sizeof(bitmapinfoheader);
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.width = _width;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.height = _height;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.planes = _planes;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.bitsperpixel = _bitsperpixel;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.compression = _compression;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.imagesize = _pixelbytesize;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.ypixelpermeter = _ypixelpermeter ;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.xpixelpermeter = _xpixelpermeter ;
    pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.numcolorspallette = 0;
    fwrite (pbitmap, 1, sizeof(bitmap),fp);
    for(i=0;i<8192;i++)
    {
    pixelbuffer[i] = arr[i];
}
 //   memset(pixelbuffer,pixel,_pixelbytesize);
    fwrite(pixelbuffer,1,_pixelbytesize,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(pbitmap);
    free(pixelbuffer);
}
```

i am giving bits per pixel is 1 bit (i want either black or white), and not sure about other parameters which has to be change.

if i use _bitsperpixel as 24 then it is working properly but if i assign as 1 then getting it is getting crashed..

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `#define _height 64`  1) do not use the leading underscore  The compiler has special use for leading underscores.  2) in general, `#define` names and struct names are typically written in ALL CAPS so they stand out from the crowd

Comment: OT:  regarding: `typedef struct {
    fileheader fileheader;
    bitmapinfoheader bitmapinfoheader;
} bitmap;`  1) this makes the struct anonymous because there is no `tag` name for the struct.  The result is difficulty in displaying the fields in the struct via a debugger because most debuggers use the `tag` name  2)  making the field names the same as the type names is a very poor programming paradigm and leads to confusing the human reader

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *fp = fopen("test.bmp","wb");`  after calling (most) C library functions, including `fopen()`  always check the returned value (in this case !=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "fopen failed" );` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: OT: regarding; `bitmap *pbitmap  = (bitmap*)calloc(1,sizeof(bitmap));` and 
    `uint8_t *pixelbuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(_pixelbytesize);`  1) these functions return a value with type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code   2) when calling these function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Note: the smallest pixel value is 8 bits for a black and white image the valid value is `0xff` or `0x00`

Comment: Note:  the width of a row (width) of an image must be a multiple of 4.  fill extra pixels with dummy values, like `0x00`.  So what ever is in the `width` field must be rounded up to a multiple of 4.  This makes the pixel field that much larger than is indicated by simply multiplying `width` by `height`

Comment: regarding; `#define _bitsperpixel 1`   This doesn't actually work  The (typical) valid values are: 8, 16, 24, and 32

Comment: regarding the definitions of the parts of the image file,  Such files are always many little arrays of char, so using things like `int32_t` is not a good idea.  And since such files are all little Endian, assigning from `int32_t` variables (depending you your hardware) can result in the wrong values being saved into the file

Comment: remember that this field: `pbitmap->bitmapinfoheader.width = _width;` does not include the fill/dummy bytes at the end of each row

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<8192;i++)
    {
    pixelbuffer[i] = arr[i];
}` and `fwrite(pixelbuffer,1,_pixelbytesize,fp);`  if 8192 and _pixelbytesize are not the same then there will be a problem

Answer (score 3):

When `_bitsperpixel == 1`, then `_pixelbytesize == 1024`. Your loop runs till `8192`, thus writing beyond the allocated memory.

Depending on what you store in your `arr`, you should either reduce the number of iterations of the loop to `_pixelbytesize`, or convert your bytes in `arr` into bits:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _pixelbytesize; ++i)
{
    uint8_t b = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        b |= arr[8*i + j] >> 7 << j;
    pixelbuffer[i] = b;
}
```

Note that this is a simple code that works only for image widths that are divisible by eight.